# Map the share to a drive letter In Parallels

Tags: macos, parallels

because Parallels names the localhost as '.psf' I have problems using Visual Studio within Parallels ('Invalid URI: Host name could not be passed' error appears). I understood that somehow I have to map a folder to a drive letter in Parallels. Can someone describe me the exact steps of how I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

First, if you haven't already, you need to tell Parallels what folder in OS X you want to share with Windows. To do this go to the "Virtual Machine" menu and select "Configure…". From there go to the "Shared Folders" section and add a new user-defined share.

Back in Windows, open My Computer and look for button in the toolbar called "Map Network Drive." It'll bring up a dialog box which lets you choose the drive letter and path to the shared folder. It's easier to just hit the Browse button and navigate to the share than to type it by hand.

Hit the Finish button and you should be all set.